# Uninstalled Jenkins but it still appears at localhost:8080

Tags: jenkins, localhost

I have uninstalled Jenkins completely from my Mac Big Sur. There are no files in

'/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command'
'/Users/Shared/Jenkins'
'/Users/jenkins'
'/Groups/jenkins'

Everything appears to be installed, but when I navigate to localhost:8080, I still get the Jenkins login page.

This makes me feel like there are more files and things that I am unaware of still in my system. Does anybody know how I can remove what ever this is that still has Jenkins running?

Comment: Have you tried checking your running processes and seeing what path they are running from?

Comment: Go to 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'System Information' , there you can see the HOME and JENKINS_HOME variables alongside other system info which will help you understand where does the Jenkins installation reside.